# Add use="required" field to XML Schema attribute programmatically

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation

Parent xsd :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="SpecialOption">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="Option" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

After modifying xsd: Adding use="required" field

```
<xs:element name="SpecialOption">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="Option" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I want to add the use="required" field to the parent xsd and generate a new xsd file.
I want to do this programmatically from a java code.

currently, I am following the below method to read the xsd file but cannot figure out a way to add the use="required" attribute
[How to Programmatically Update and Add Elements to an XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592796/how-to-programmatically-update-and-add-elements-to-an-xsd)

Any help here is very much appreciated.Thank you

Comment: Why? Text editor broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use XSLT. Assuming XSLT 3.0:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:template match="xs:element[@name='SpecialOption']//xs:attribute[@name='Option']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="use">required</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

It's not difficult with earlier versions of XSLT, just a bit more verbose.

(You asked for Java, but of course you can easily run an XSLT transformation from Java, and this is much easier than hand-coding it with low-level DOM manipulation).

Comment: The parent xsd is obtained from a supplier, I want to keep the same format with only use="required" field added and generate a new .xsd file. And, I wanted to modify the parent xsd file in java.   What I am looking for is that the generated xsd file will be exactly same as the parent xsd but only the required attribue should be made mandatory.

Comment: Yes, I thought that's what you wanted and that's what my solution does.

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: @MichaelKay Thank you for the answer. I applied the transform provided by you via java code.The required field is added but the parent tags are removed.This is how the transformed xsd looks now. ** <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
        
            
                
                    <xs:attribute xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="Option" type="xs:string" use="required"/>**

Comment: Added this code before the code @MichaelKay provided, works fine    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: I did say you would need extra code if you wanted to use an earlier version of XSLT pre-3.0...