# Inserting elements in xml

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to add elements to xml. I followed [Java DOM - Inserting an element, after another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405055/java-dom-inserting-an-element-after-another) 
but that did not work for me. Here is my code:

```
Element e = dom.createElement("mapping");
e.setAttribute("resource", "/some/path/to/file");
Element lastChild = (Element)nList.item(nList.getLength()-1);
Element parent= (Element)nList.item(nList.getLength()-1).getParentNode();

lastChild.getParentNode().insertBefore(e, lastChild);
```

I also tried `parent.appendChild(e);` but none of them work. It doesn't seem like there is problem with the code. What could be the problem?

I am using Netbeans on macosx. Is this because of file permissions ?

Comment: "*It doesn't seem like there is problem with the code.*" What makes you think that?

Comment: Because I have tested it a couple of times and there are no errors. Also there arent any logical flaws and this same snippet seems to work for others.

Comment: A lack of errors simply means the code successfully does *something*, it doesn't mean it does *what you want*.  If the same snippet works for others, there's clearly a "logical" flaw in your code, though perhaps not in that snippet in particular.

Comment: For instance, how do you know this code isn't "working"?  It's likely `e` is in fact being inserted before `lastChild`, but whatever you're doing to verify this is incorrect.

Comment: *"Is this because of file permissions?"* Maybe? We're not on your computer, so we can't answer specifics about your environment.  Try writing a quick test that reads the file as text; if it reads it, you have read permission.

Comment: Shouldnt I see an entry in xml file. There is none. Also when I do getLastChild I dont see the new addition.

Comment: I have read write permissions.

Comment: You should only see change *in the file* if you write your data back to the file.  The code snippet you shared is not editing the file, it is modifying an in-memory DOM.

Comment: Also you're calling `.insertBefore()` - the last child will still be `lastChild` after that call.

Comment: I tested lastChild with appendChild to parent. Anyways I think I got the answer I was looking for, I will look into how to write DOM modified data back to file. If you can post that as an answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Element`s you are working with are a DOM in memory, they are not directly tired to your file contents. The code snippet you posted only modifies that DOM. You will only see change *in the file* if you write your data back to the file.